# How to get the section when click on the respective links in the fixed header

Tags: html, css

Scenario: When I click on the title1 link in the fixed header, it should display title1 section and when I click on title2 link it should display title 2 section on the top like that..but here it's displaying on the top of the page but behind the header, so it's not visible

I have attached the code which I tried, Please help to resolve this

```css
.menu {
    height: 165px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: -113px;
    width: 1090px;
}

#menu-center ul {
    margin:35px 0 0px 115px
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
 .Avatar1{
  background: #ED7D31;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  }
  .Avatar2{
background: #A5A5A5;
 border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  }
  .Avatar3{
background: #FFC000;
 border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  }
  .Avatar4{
background: #5b9bd5;
 border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  }
   .Avatar5{
background: #70AD47;
 border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  }
 div.item {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
 color:#ffffff;
}
 
#Title1 {
 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   
 padding-top: 165px; 

  
}
#Title2 {    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
padding-top: 25px; 
}
#Title3{    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
 padding-top: 25px;
}

#Title4 {    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
 padding-top: 25px;
}
#Title5 {    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
 padding-top: 280px;
}
  .vertical { 
            border-left: 190px solid #5786c5; 
          
         margin-left:900px; 
    margin-top: -1620px;
    height: 1620px;
        } 
.items-01{
margin-right: 253px;
    font-size: 16px;
line-height:1.8;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table width="1094px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<h2 style="
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -150px;">Heading</h2>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#Title1"><div class="item"><img src="picture.png" class="Avatar1" width="50" height="50" > <span class="caption">Title1</span></div></a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#Title2"><div class="item"><img src="picture.png" class="Avatar2" width="50" height="50" > <span class="caption">Title2​</span></div></a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#Title3"><div class="item"><img src="picture.png" class="Avatar3" width="50" height="50" > <span class="caption">Title3</span></div></a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#Title4"><div class="item"><img src="picture.png" class="Avatar4" width="50" height="50" > <span class="caption">Title4</span></div></a>

            </li>
    </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link"  href="#objective"><div class="item"><img src="picture.png" class="Avatar5" width="50" height="50" > <span class="caption">Title5</span></div></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:0px;">
<div class="content" id="Title1">
    <h1 style = "color: #333333;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">  
        Title1
</h1>  
<ul>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content" id="Title2" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <h1 style = "color: #333333;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">  
         Title2
</h1>  
<ul>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content" id="Title3" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <h1 style = "color: #333333;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">  
         Title3
</h1>  
<ul>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type.
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content" id="Title4" style="margin-top:0px;">
 <h1 style = "color: #333333;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">  
        Title4
</h1>  
<ul>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content" id="Title5" style="margin-top:0px;" >
<h1 style = "color: #333333;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">    
        Title5
</h1> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/>
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>


 
<ul>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>
<li class="items-01">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</li>


</ul>

  </div>  
  
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to add padding to the section equal to the height of your menu.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using javascript and jquery library.

- Import jquery library to your code.
- use this below code inside a script tag.

> ```
> $('#menu-center ul').find('a').click(function(e){
>
>         e.preventDefault();
>
>         var menuHeight = $('.menu').height();
>         var $href = $(this).attr('href');
>         var $anchor = $($href).offset(); // Get position of section.
>
>         //Scroll particular section to top with adjusting menu height.
>         window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top- menuHeight);
>
>         return false;
>
>     });
> ```

Comment: @dhananjyan Thank you for your reply. And it works! .But I want to implement this on SharePoint page, there import of jquery library is not working. Is there any way to do this without javascript?

Comment: @Ann it can be only done by javascript. I think this might help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91981/how-to-add-jquery-library-in-sharepoint-2013.